# Refactoring a series of integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Suppose I have a non-negative function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) dxdy < \infty$. Given two real numbers $a<b$, I define the function $f$ as follows:

$f(x,y) = g(x,y) + \int_a^b g(x,z)g(z,y)dz $

$+ \int_a^b \int_a^b  g(x,z_1)g(z_1,z_2)g(z_2,y) dz_2dz_1 $

$+ \int_a^b \int_a^b \int_a^b g(x,z_1)g(z_1,z_2)g(z_2,z_3)g(z_3,y) dz_3dz_2dz_1 $

$+ \; ... $

Is there a name for this process? And can I obtain a more compact expression for $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an operator $G$ by

$$
(Gh)(x,y)=\int_a^bg(x,z)h(z,y)\,\mathrm dz\;.
$$

Then

$$
f = \sum_{k=0}^\infty G^kg=\frac1{1-G}g\;,
$$

where the last equality is of course to be taken with a grain of salt and may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Interesting! So you are generalizing the geometric series to functions, in a sense. Is there a standard ``mapping" to regular power series in order to be able to apply results from that area? And is $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} : |G^kg|<1$ sufficient for the last equality to hold?

Comment: Um... that is obviously not sufficient :) Rather, the question is, what would be analogous to the convergence criterion of $|x|<1$ in the case of geometric series.

Comment: @mitchus: You may want to read up on [spectral theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory), especially the sections on the [resolvent operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory#Resolvent_operator) and on [operator equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory#Operator_equations). Roughly speaking, the criterion is that if you expand $g$ in eigenfunctions of $G$, the magnitudes of the corresponding eigenvalues must be less than $1$. You also have $Gf=f$, so $f$ is an eigenfunction of $G$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @mitchus: Sorry, that last sentence was wrong; the equation is $Gf=g+f$, so $f$ isn't an eigenfunction of $G$.